# How do you comment muliple lines of python code in IDLE on MACBOOK?

Tags: python, comments, python-idle

I have been trying to figure out how to comment multiple lines of python code in `IDLE` shell on MACBOOK pro apple silicon

I have tried to comment with **command+D, Command+1, control+D, control+1** but none of the options I tried did work.

Comment: try `Command + /`

Comment: Thanks for the response but Command + / – did not work

Answer (score 0):

add ''' in beginning and end of code block
Here is a code example

```
print('this is print 1')
'''
print('this is inside comments line 1')
print('this is inside comments line 2')
'''
print('this is print 2')
```

and after running in this in IDLE the output is

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

= RESTART: C:\Users\User\Documents\Python scripts\Stack overflow solutions\multiline comment\test multi line comment.py
this is print 1
this is print 2
```

as you can see the the lines between ''' is not executed meaning they have been commented out

Comment: Hi Vishnu Balaji, thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if you would extend your answer to provide more explanations -- and maybe a demonstrating code snippet -- to your answer. -- [Low Quality Anwers Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33789780)

Comment: ''' is used in a string definition defined over multiples lines. It does not comment the code. At the end of the string say for example on 10th line, you place ''' to end the string.

Answer (score 0):

On the IDLE Format menu, 'region' usually means 'selected lines.  'Comment out region' and 'Uncomment region' do what they say to a selected region.  The default hot keys for Windows and Mac and perhaps Linux are Control-3 and Control-4.

Shell is read-only except for the statement entry area at the bottom -- the line marked with the last >>> prompt and below.  So commenting out code above this area is not possible and in this area it has much less use than in an editor.

Comment: Spyder, for exaple has command+1 to Comment out and PyCharm has Command+/. Likewise, IDLE editor must also have some shortcut for commenting multiple lines of code. I have tried all options but none has worked.

Comment: I gave the answer for IDLE above, Control-3, *after* I tested on my Macbook Air with Catalina.  It works on the latest versions of 3.10, 3.11, 3.12.  There could be a problem with later hardware or macOS version, but please test carefully.